# Order by specific values from a column without CASE

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

I have an Order table with Id and Name

```
1  Fruits
33 Liquor
48 Tennis bats
58 Vegetables 
95 Poker cards

SELECT * FROM Order ORDER BY... Id = (48, 95, 33, 1, 58)
```

And the result should be

```
48 Tennis bats
95 Poker cards
33 Liquor
1  Fruits
58 Vegetables
```

### **Q:** How can I order this records by the values of a column I want ?

I want to make a general function(maybe a stored proc.) out of this so I **can't** use the CASE method:

```
CASE WHEN Id=48 THEN 0 ELSE 1  END, -- Not this way!!!!
```

Comment: What is the logic behind this order?

Comment: I think you should add another column that would store values by which the sorting is performed.

Comment: Actually I have another table, let's say d.DeliverySheet(d 1 - * order) and I was thinking of putting a column there : d.LoadingOrder = '48, 95, 33, 1, 58'

Comment: I didn't want to put another column in the Order table so it would get too crowded.

Comment: @Misi You could do that, you would have to join the tables then, but that is easy to implement and shouldn't hurt the performance if indices are appropriately set.

Comment: if you want give the order using the column d.LoadingOrder = '48, 95, 33, 1, 58' you should generate a temporary table from this information, where have the id and the position.. join it with your Order table and order by the position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table [Order] (
  ID int, Name varchar(32)
)

insert into [Order]
  values (1, 'Fruits'),
         (33, 'Liquor'),
         (48, 'Tennis bats'),
         (58, 'Vegetables'),
         (95, 'Poker cards')
GO

create function dbo.Orderer(@id int, @orderString varchar(1024))
returns int
as
begin
  set @orderString = replace(',' + @orderString + ',', ' ', '');

  declare @pos int, 
          @str varchar(1024), 
          @itemOrder int;

  set @pos = charindex(',' + cast(@id as varchar(16)) + ',', @orderString);
  if @pos != 0
  begin
    set @orderString = substring(@orderString, 1, @pos + 1);
    set @pos = charindex(',', @orderString);
    set @itemOrder = 0;

    while @pos != 0
    begin
      set @itemOrder += 1;

      set @pos = charindex(',', @orderString, @pos + 1);
    end

    return @itemOrder
  end

  return null
end
GO

select * from [Order]
order by dbo.Orderer(ID, '48, 95, 33, 1, 58')
```